# Checkboxes aren't filled in correctly when searching a list

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js

A have a form where companies should be able to fill in information and then register to the site.

One of the things that they should be able to fill in is what category they belong to ie CRM, accounting software, ERP etc and they should be able to choose several options
in the list.
Though the list is quite long so they also have to be able to search it.
The foundation of this works but I realise that if I choose several of these categories (that are on the top of the list) and then start to search the list then (sometimes) I find that when I empty the search field some of the categories aren't clicked in anymore.

I have added an image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44agR.png) of when I have clicked in a couple of categories, then searched and then emptied the search field. Thereafter some categories are not checked but their checked value is still true.

**Backend code** (this is only run ones, i.e when loading the category list)

```
@app.route("/get_categories")
def get_categories():
    search_item = request.args.get("search_item")
    categories_query = Session.query(enjordplatformCategories ).all()
                                                                           

show_categories_list =[]
show_categories_dictionary=[]
i=0
for category in categories_query:
    show_categories_dictionary = {
        'i':i,
        'id' : category.id,
        'category' :category.subcategory_name_english,
        'checked':False
    }

    show_categories_list.append(show_categories_dictionary)
    i=i+1
response = json.dumps(show_categories_list)
return response
```

**Frontend code**

*HTML*

```
    <input type="text" class="search_ruta_input" v-model="search_category"  placeholder="Search Category" v-on:keyup="search_category_func(search_category)"  >

  
      <div v-for="(category,idx) in this.filtered_category_list" :key="idx">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_new"  :value="category.checked" v-if="!category.checked" @click="choose_category(category)">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_filled"  :value="category.checked" v-if="category.checked" @click="choose_category(category)">
        {{category.category}} {{category.checked}} 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Scripts

```
methods:{
        load_category(search_category){
          var self = this
          axios({
              method:'get',
              url: API_URL+ '/get_categories'+'?search_item='+search_category,
            })
            .then(function(response){
                self.category_list = response.data
            })
        },
        search_category_func(search_category){
            this.filtered_category_list =  this.category_list.filter(
              category_object =>  category_object.category.toLowerCase().includes(search_category.toLowerCase())
            )
              category => (category.category + " " + category.checked)
            ))
    
        },
        
    choose_category(category_object){
          this.category_list = this.category_list.map(category => {
            if (category.id == category_object.id){
                category.checked = category.checked === false ? true : false
    
            }
                return category
          })    
     },

}
mounted(){
this.load_category("")

setTimeout(() => {
    this.search_category_func("")
  }, 1000);
}
```

How can I resolve this?
thanks

Comment: Can you make a minimized example? There is so much here. Like are the style tags actually required; does the error still happen without the styles?

Comment: Hi
Sorry of course. I removed all of that so hopefully it is easier to read. The style tags should not have anything to do with the issue.